# MySQL: get table data but join another table if the id matach

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-4

My tables

```
pets
pet_lost
```

Give me all `pets` `where user_id = 1` ... but also include `pet_lost` data if `pet_lost.pet_id = pets.id`

I always want to bring in `pets` `where user_id = 1`, but I want to access the `pet_lost` data if there's a connection...

Make sense?

Comment: "*Make sense?*" Not entirely, no - although it sounds as though you *may* be after an outer join: see [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Comment: That is a `LEFT JOIN`.  `...FROM pets LEFT JOIN pet_lost ON pets.id = pet_lost.pet_id`

Comment: I tried the `LEFT JOIN`, but it seems to only give me results where both conditions are true ... remember, I want to get the `pet` data no matter what

Comment: If you've tried something, why don't you show that in your question?  Together with a sample of your data and the results you're obtaining, alongside those you expect, we might actually be in a position to help (rather than guess).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate this into a query using a `left outer join` and an appropriate `where` clause:

```
select *
from pets p left outer join
     pet_lost pl
     on pl.pet_id = p.id
where p.user_id = 1 or pl.pet_id is not null;
```

EDIT:

You can phrase this as:

```
select p.*
from pets p
where p.user_id = 1 or
      p.id in (select pl.pet_id from pet_lost);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you have 2 tables but from what I see I would have put a binary field in the pets column for a yes or no indication as to the pets status.

But if you are going to keep your tables as they are then you would use a "Union" query to bring the 2 tables together.

Keep in mind that there cannot be lost pet id's in the pets table.

I would recommend the binary field in the pets table and delete the pets lost table.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but there is data that I need to store related to the status ...

Comment: where would you recommend I store that data if not in it's own table?

Comment: I'm sorry if my reply is late i'm new and also working on other projects. If you can post your fields or columns I can help you normalize them. Or if you can find a book or link on data normalizing it will help you design the tables better